# How do I get file metadata in Dolphin?

Tags: fedora, kde, dolphin, file-metadata

On Fedora 26 KDE I don't get any metadata for files (video/audio duration, picture size, etc.) in Dolphin. I have tried various settings from [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332065), particularly [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332065#c30), but to no avail. Can anyone let me know how to make Dolphin show metadata?

Comment: This is surely one of the most annoying and inexplicable omissions of modern computing systems.